# How do I get an iterable object of function properties?

Tags: javascript, function, properties

It can be necessary to access all the object's properties in the case of using JavaScript objects to describe "*binding*" data to UI view.

Real usecase may be building dynamically changeable edit box.
[image]

Is there any way to get the object containing all the function fields (with no functions and objects)?

```
function Airplane() {
    _id,
    _cruiserSpeed,
    _maxWeightCapacity,
    _maxFlightHeight,
    _fuelState,
    _airCompanyOwner,
    _seats = []

    this.fly = function(departurePoint, destinationPoint) {

    }
}
```

So that we can iterate through them like this..

```
for (var field in context.fields) {

}
```

Does language support this reflection in general? (may be over one of *proto* properties)

Now, the only solution figured out is to use nested objects. But it adds more complexity to simple access to properties (**context._id** is **context._fields._id**).

```
function Airplane() {
    this._fields = {
        _id,
        _cruiserSpeed,
        _maxWeightCapacity,
        _maxFlightHeight,
        _fuelState,
        _airCompanyOwner,
        _seats = []
    }

    this.fly = function(departurePoint, destinationPoint) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you could iterate over all properties of an object and filter out those that are functions...?

Comment: What do you mean by *"Is there any way to get the object containing all the function fields (with no functions and objects)?"*? You mean their names? Which names, the ones that refer to functions and objects, or the ones that don't? Or do you mean a new object with the properties referring to functions and objects? (Or without them?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily tell whether a property refers to a function in a `for-in` loop:

```
for (var name in object) {
    if (typeof object[name] === "function") {
        // It's a function
    } else {
        // It isn't
    }
}
```

(There used to be issues in old browsers where some functions provided by the browser said `"object"` instead of `"function"`, but those are obsolete now.)

You can also tell if it refers to an object, by using `=== "object"` instead of `=== "function"`.

It's not clear from your question what you want (the property names, a new object with just a subset of the properties) and whether you do/don't want functions and objects, but that should get you pointed the right way.

[More about `typeof` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

For instance, if you wanted an array of the names of properties that didn't refer to a function or object:

```
var names = [];
for (var name in object) {
    switch (typeof object[name]) {
        case "function":
        case "object":
            break;
        default:
            names.push(name);
            break;
}
```

*(I'm not using `Object.keys` or `Object.entries` there because you mentioned wanting to visit inherited properties.)*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It made absolutely clear how to iterate through the properties and categorize them. And it's better example to understand the language than just using **Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)**.

Comment: @MaxBender - Glad to help! I didn't mention `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` for the same reason as `Object.keys` and such: It doesn't do inherited ones (but does do non-enumerable ones). If you want non-enumerable ones including inherited ones, you'd use a loop with `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` and `Object.getPrototypeOf` to step up to the prototype (stopping at an appropriate point, such as when you reach `Object.prototype`). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46784081/157247) has an example of that. Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

you just need to use the "typeof" operator -

```
for(var prop in obj){
if((typeof obj[prop] !== 'object') && (typeof obj[prop] !== 'function')){
 // do whatever you want
}}
```